Selenium - How to get attributes of href under specific parent class in Python
I'm trying to get the href attribute that is under a specific class.
This is an example of the HTML:

This class and href is repeated multiple times throughout the page
I have tried the below, however this only grabs the top one. Im trying to grab all instances of the href.
Link to the page I'm scraping:
https://www.domain.com.au/sale/toowoomba-qld-4350/?bedrooms=3-any&price=0-600000&excludeunderoffer=1
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='slick-slide slick-active slick-current']")
links = element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='https://www.domain.com.au']")
urls = []
for link in links:
    urls.append(link.get_attribute("href"))
    print(urls)


# Parent element
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='slick-slide slick-active slick-current']")

# Anchor tags
links = element .find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='https://www.domain.com.au']")

# All urls 
urls = [l.get_attribute('href') for l in links]


You should first get all matching elements and then get their href
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='slick-slide slick-active slick-current']")
urls = []
for element in elements:
    urls.append(elements.get_attribute("href"))
    print(urls)

But，this may match elements that do not have href attributes.You may need to add some conditions or exception handling.
Plus，I see that in your example the href is in the a tag, please write your XPATH
